# np.argsort with duplicate entries: make deterministic?

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

When `argsort`ing a numpy entry with duplicate entries, the output isn't deterministic, e.g., from

```py
import numpy as np

print(np.argsort([4, 2, 0, 6, 4, 3, 7, 6, 5, 7, 1, 2]))
```

I sometimes get

```py
[ 2 10  1 11  5  0  4  8  3  7  6  9]
```

and other times

```py
[ 2 10 11  1  5  0  4  8  3  7  6  9]
#       !  !
```

(I noticed that when testing a software with Python 3.12, not sure if this has anything to do with it.)

Both results are correct, so I can't call this a bug. Is there a way to make the result deterministic, e.g., but enforcing smaller array indices to go before larger ones?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/24064 and tried asking for a `'stable'` sort?

Comment: run the argsort 10million times in  numpy `1.26.3` and got the same results in all of them. Cannot replicate the problem

Comment: @Onyambu Now run in on 10 million different machines, Python versions, architectures.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
#Stable Version of Numpy
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([4, 2, 0, 6, 4, 3, 7, 6, 5, 7, 1, 2])

# Use stable sort to maintain original order for equal elements
sorted_indices = np.argsort(arr, kind='stable')

print(sorted_indices)
```

For **older** version of numpy

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([4, 2, 0, 6, 4, 3, 7, 6, 5, 7, 1, 2])

# Create an array of indices
indices = np.arange(len(arr))

# Sort by indices, then by the original array
sorted_indices = np.lexsort((arr, indices))

print(sorted_indices)
```